# jQuery dynamic tab colours (all except one tab)

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a UL with the class of "tabs"
one li has a class of "active"

The "active" tab obviously changes as a user clicks on a different tab and is used so the colour of it is different to the rest.

What i want to do is select all the Li's within the "tabs" UL EXCEPT for the active one and set each one a different colour by appending CSS background for each.
The amount of tabs can differ depending on which page they are on I.E one page may have four tabs but another may have 6 or 7.

If i was grabbing them all i wouldnt have a problem but im not sure how to go about it to try and exclude the active tab since i had planned on using Nth which would INCLUDE the active tab?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you using jQuery UI tabs? or just jQuery with your own tab setup

Comment: I want to use jquery with my own tab setup

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('ul.tabs li').not('.active').css({ ... });
```

You can then iterate through them using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('ul.tabs li').not('.active').each(function() { ... });
```

**Edit:** Assuming then that you have some way of determining which tab should have which background, here is an example of this in use: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcwXJ/).

Comment: You haven't understood my question. That is what i already have and isn't what i asked

Comment: this almost works. When the page loads a tab is already set as active - when you change from this tab it uses the default css for the tab colour instead of what i have set as data-background? All the rest work fine when clicked on or off. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Well `data-background` here is simply a HTML5 [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). It's simply a way of holding custom data for a specific element. I'm a bit confused by what you mean though, as surely the background colours here should only apply when a tab *isn't* `.active`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "active" is what is applied to the tab container when its clicked and all tabs have something like class="tab" something like this should suffice.

```
$(".tab").each(funciton() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active"))
    {
            $(this).addClass("myBackground");
    }
});
```

Comment: above answer (not mine) is way better :)

Comment: How do i have the first Li that is NOT active set to blue then the second Li that is NOT active red then the third Li that is not active green using this method? Maybe i'm not following you correctly or i'm not explaining very well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in css3 you can use this:

```
:not(p)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

This sets a background color for all elements that are not a "p" element.
More info: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/